# Applying PID Controller for trajectory planning algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, robotics, pid-controller

I am developing a path planning algorithm for a Segway robot. After running the algorithm path to the goal is obtained in form of `(x, y, theta)` coordinates. The hardware and sensor noises causing much trouble in following the path and error is accumulating. I thought of applying PID Control. I need to set the steering angle to the direction of movement by calculating the cross track error.

1) How to calculate the CTE with original co-ordinate `(x1, y1, theta1)` and current position `(x1', y1', theta1')`?

2) How to select values for *K<sub>p</sub>*, *K<sub>i</sub>* and *K<sub>d</sub>* for this scenario?

Additional information: Development environment is Android studio.

Comment: what do you refer to by CTE?

Comment: Cross track error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the *K<sub>p</sub>*, *K<sub>i</sub>*, *K<sub>d</sub>* values either experimentally or with a method like [Ziegler-Nichols Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method) which would be more accurate.

Experimentally, you can try:

1. Set all gains to 0.
2. Increase *K<sub>d</sub>* until the system oscillates.
3. Reduce *K<sub>d</sub>* by a factor of 2-4.
4. Set *K<sub>p</sub>* to about 1% of *K<sub>d</sub>*.
5. Increase *K<sub>p</sub>* until oscillations start.
6. Decrease *K<sub>p</sub>* by a factor of 2-4.
7. Set *K<sub>i</sub>* to about 1% of *K<sub>p</sub>*.
8. Increase *K<sub>i</sub>* until oscillations start.
9. Decrease *K<sub>i</sub>* by a factor of 2-4.